# Create out-of-bag chart of RF model classification in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

Can I create such out-of-bag chart of RF model classification in GEE?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the below.  I don't think this will work for any larger counts of trees or any heavy classifications.

```
var treeCounts = ee.List.sequence(1, 100)
var errors = treeCounts.map(getOutOfBagErrorEstimate)
var chart = ui.Chart.array.values({
  array: errors, 
  axis: 0, 
  xLabels: treeCounts
})
print(chart)

function getOutOfBagErrorEstimate(trees) {
  var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(trees)
    .train(training, 'class')
  return classifier.explain().getNumber('outOfBagErrorEstimate')
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ef795d768ff542516fed34f58b5c0c5f